# How to add anaconda module import path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda

I installed some python modules using pip

They were installed in `usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages`

Later I installed anaconda and seems anaconda didn't look for modules in this path, and return `ImportError: No module named 'selenium'`

But seems PyCharm can recognize this path. Is there any way that I can add the above path to anaconda that it can look for modules in this path? I know `sys.path.append` , but I want a more concise way.